# HashCode у класса String в Java

Tags: java, строки, hashcode

Разбирался я тут со строками и на одном ресурсе прочитал следующий тезис:

> Поскольку строка неизменная, её hashcode кэшируется в момент создания и нет необходимости рассчитывать его снова.

Полез я в `java.lang.String` и увидел что хоть метод `hashCode()` там и есть, но в самом коде этот метод нигде не вызывается. Я правильно понимаю, что, по факту, при создании строк хэш не используется и тезис в начале неверен?

Comment: имелось в виду "хэшкод кэшируется в момент создания [**хэшкода**]"

Answer (score 4):

Тезис  верен.
Значение хэшкода вычисляется в момент первого вызовы `hashCode` и сохраняется в поле объекта. При том, метод может несколько раз вычислить значение, из разных потоков, т.к. никакой синхронизации для данного поля не предусмотрено.

Comment: Таки тезис верен, просто он не о создании строки.

Comment: @Artem Konovalov:  "из разных потоков" хешкод для одного объекта будет всегда одинаковый?

Comment: @TimurVI да, он подсчитывается на основе массива символов, из которых состоит строка, емнип

Comment: @Anon двусмысленное утверждение и его трактовать можно как в момент создания строки так и в момент вычисления значения.  А если тут речь про вычисление, то как можно сказать о значение что оно было создано?

Comment: Вообщем поменял на верен, но не суть. Из пояснения к ответу думаю и так все ясно.